# Getting a 'Method not found' Error using Connect-PnPOnline

Tags: pnp-powershell

Trying to use Connect-PnPOnline to access SPO to run PowerShell script.

PS>Connect-PnPOnline -Url $tenancy -Credentials $mySPOCredentials
Connect-PnPOnline : Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQueryAsync()'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-PnPOnline -Url $tenancy -Credentials $mySPOCredentials
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], MissingMethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMethodException,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline

Gives the above error.
Updated SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline Module - still doesn't work
Re-installed PnPOnline from .MSI - still doesn't work

Comment: get-module -Name SharePointPnp*     Can you run this powershell command and share the snapshot ?

Comment: PS>get-module -Name SharePointPnp* | select ModuleType, Version, Name

ModuleType Version     Name  
---------- -------     ----  
    Binary 2.27.1806.0 SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

Comment: Can you try to uninstall SharePoint Client Components (if you had installed) completely? and Then install the latest one. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Uninstalled SharePoint Client Components Version 16.0.6518.1200 and then  Installed Version 16.0.6906.1200.   Same error.  :(

Comment: I have looked at the PnP GitHub issues. People have tried to remove it from GAC, the SharePoint assemblies to get around the issue. I would suggest you to raise an issue there so that more people who faced this issue might help. Sorry, couldn't be of much assistance.

Comment: @Arvi  Thanks very much for trying.  I appreciate the effort.  :)